# Как определить кастомный экшен для Yii2 RestApi контроллера

Tags: yii2, rest

Задача следующая - есть rest api ресурс на движке yii2, для него нужно переделать экшены index, view, create, delete, update, чтоб реализовать свою логику для этих действий. Экшен index переопределил, а вот при переопределении view возникает ошибка при обращении к нему:

```
Setting unknown property: yii\rest\ViewAction::prepareDataProvider
```

Переопределяю экшены следующим образом:

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();

    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'actionIndex'];
    $actions['view']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'actionView'];

    return $actions;
}
public function actionView($id)
{
    return([$id]);
}
```

Как мне переделать экшен так, чтоб это работало?

Answer (score 1):

В общем я делал эту задачу руководствуясь неполным либо неверным туториалом. Покопавшись в исходниках yii я нашел что в классе экшена есть другая функция, отвечающая за формирования данных. Делать нужно так:

```
    $actions['view']['findModel'] = [$this, 'actionView'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function actions()
  {
      $actions = parent::actions();
      
      // Выключает действие `actionIndex()`, которое определенно по умолчанию
      unset($actions['index']);

      return $actions;
  }
  
  // Переопределяем действие actionIndex()
  public function actionIndex()
  {   
    // Возвращаем данные из модели, которая расширена классом `ActiveRecord`
    return User::find()->all();
  }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Сделал. Вроде бы должно быть понятно.